# Join two tables by column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have two table, say comment_table and post_table,

comment_table:

```
link_id   body
t3_100    people on StackOverflow are smart 
t3_100    StackOverflow is a good place to raise questions
t3_101    where can I learn sql 
t3_102    Happy Eastern
t3_102    where did my bunny go?
```

post_table

```
id      title
100     Thought on StackOverflow
101     sql beginner
102     Eastern 
105     Title that has no comments
```

"link_id" is concatenated by 't3_' + id from post_table. What I want is two join this two tables by "id".

Expected Output

```
id      title                        link_id   body
100     Thought on StackOverflow     t3_100    people on StackOverflow are smart
100     Thought on StackOverflow     t3_100    StackOverflow is a good place to raise questions
101     sql beginner                 t3_101    where can I learn sql 
102     Eastern                      t3_102    Happy Eastern
102     Eastern                      t3_102    where did my bunny go?
105     Title that has no comments   t3_105    NULL
```

Here is the script I have,

```
SELECT PT.ID, PT.title, CT.link_id, CT.body  
FROM post_table as PT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_table as CT
ON PT.ID = CT.concat('t3_', link_id)
```

It has syntax error, how do you think I can fix this to get the expected output?

Comment: The error message should tell you where the syntax error is located. Edit your question, and add the full error message.

Comment: in any case you have the two table-aliases (PT and CT) switched in the last line of your script, meaning you have to concatenate the PT.ID, not the CT.link_id. Try changing that first. Luc

Comment: Why don't you just store integers in `link_id`? The way you're doing it, you can't define a foreign key. And if you ever need to join the other way around, you won't be able to use an index for the join.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning alias with function, it should be with field.

This would work.

```
SELECT PT.ID, PT.title, CT.link_id, CT.body  
FROM post_table as PT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_table as CT
ON CT.link_id = CONCAT('t3_', PT.ID)
```

Comment: Here is what I get, "Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. ."

Comment: @Bobby Are you sure you're using mysql?  That error seems specific to BigQuery.

Comment: @Bobby I think you shouldn't have tagged the question with mysql.

Comment: You need to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT PT.ID, PT.title, CT.link_id, CT.body  
FROM post_table AS PT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_table AS CT
ON CT.link_id = CONCAT('t3_', PT.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't quite using `concat` properly.  Try this:

```
SELECT PT.ID, PT.title, CT.link_id, CT.body  
FROM post_table as PT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_table as CT
ON CT.link_id = concat('t3_', PT.id)
```

The `link_id` in the `comment_table` is the one with "t3_", so you want to concatenate "t3_" with the `id` from the `post_table`.

Also, it's pretty awful to have to join the tables like that.  It would be better to just have `post_id` in the `comment_table`, and if you need to append "t3_" to it for some reason, do it in the `SELECT`:

```
Select PT.ID, PT.title, concat('t3_', PT.id) link_id, CT.body
```

**Update**

Since it is now apparent that you are using BigQuery and not mysql, the above answer doesn't apply.  I'm not very familiar with BigQuery, but you might try:

```
SELECT PT.ID, PT.title, CT.link_id, CT.body  
FROM post_table as PT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_table as CT
ON CT.link_id = 't3_' + PT.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the syntax itself, but it seems more sensible to do:

```
concat('t3_', PT.ID) = CT.link_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch on your `ON PT.ID = CT.concat('t3_', link_id)` condition. Use the below SQL.

```
SELECT PT.ID, PT.title, CT.link_id, CT.body  
FROM post_table as PT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_table as CT
ON (CT.link_id = concat('t3_',PT.ID ))
```